# Finding SOLR entries without specific field

Tags: solr

I have a solr index and I need to find all entries without a specific field.

Example: my docs have a field "fruit" and it can take one of this value: "apple","orange" or could not be valorized at all.

How I can find all records without a value for fruit field?

I've tried query like `fq=-valueOfField` but it doesn't work as I need, it search every record with field "fruit" filled and remove the ones with "valueOfField", so it exclude records i need.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch all the records in which specific field is not present. Then you can try below query.

```
fq=-fruit:*
or
fq=-fruit:[* TO *]
```

You can use any one of them.
Above query will give you all the docs in which **fruit** field is not present.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, I think it works on entries with field empty. in my index this field for certain entries is not indexed at all.

Comment: For this to work, indexed should be true for that field and it will give you the documents in which this field is not there.